# jquery close outside div not working on iOS but is on Android

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I've got this little bit of JS

var $tooltips = $('.tooltip__link');

```
// tooltip/overlay toggle
$tooltips.on('click', function(){
  var tooltip = $(this);
  tooltip.toggleClass('js-opened');
  return false;
});

// remove tooltip if clicked anywhere else
// only works on 'desktop'
$('body').on('click', function() {
  $tooltips.removeClass('js-opened');
});
```

which indeed removes the class 'js-opened' on desktop browsers and indeed on Android 4+ when clicking outside the element, but fails completely to work on iOS(7) and Android 2.3

Anyone know why this code would do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `touchstart`:

```
$tooltips.on('click touchstart', function(){
  var tooltip = $(this);
  tooltip.toggleClass('js-opened');
  return false;
});

$('body').on('click touchstart', function(){
    $tooltips.removeClass('js-opened');
});
```

If this don't work try to add `cursor: pointer` to your elements. It's kind of a workaround for iOS.

Comment: I've tried this but the second snippet of jQuery (the body one) hijacks anything else on the page. Any ideas around that?

Comment: @StuartRobson What do you mean by hijacks anything else? Setup a http://jsfiddle.net/ and I can give you further help.